# fetching data but not displaying it into the innerhtml list

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch, html-lists

so i have a list of items that needs to be presented from a server, i fetched the data and checked the network and it seems fine..
but whenever i want to access the list items as an array and iterate through them, it is not working.. or else the issue is different? i'm still learning, and i have lots to learn before i can ask a normal question here.. i do not even know if this is the right issue here.
can someone review my code and provide me with my mistakes?
maybe even explaining for a few minutes so i can actually learn something instead of just finish the assignment?

JavaScript:

```
const URL =`https://stock-exchange-dot-full-stack-course-services.ew.r.appspot.com/api/v3/search?query=&limit=10&exchange=NASDAQ`;
const searchInpt = document.getElementById('searchInput');
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('searchButton');
const results = document.getElementById('displayResults');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', grabData);
function grabData() {
    spinner.style.display = "block";
    fetch(URL).then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    }).then((data) => {
        presentData(data);
    })
}
function presentData(data) {
    
        const listComp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        listComp = data[i].name + " " + data[i].symbol;
        results.innerHTML += `<li style="list-style: none;"><a href="./company.html?symbol=${data[i].symbol}" target="_blank">${listComp}</a></li>`;
            spinner.style.display = 'none';
         }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <span id="inputHolder"><input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="aa">
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button> </span>
    <div id="nasdaqUl"> 
        
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
          </div>

        
        <ul id="nasdaqLi">
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            <li class="displayResults"></li>
            
            
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</span>
<script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
    <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("displayResults")`   Your HTML doesn't have any elements with that ID.   You have plenty with a class `displayResults` though,..

Comment: Assuming you get a valid data back from the fetch, the error lies probably in the fact that your are trying to insert <li>-elements in <li>-elements. You should use ```const results = document.getElementById('nasdaqLi');``` if this is the place meant to show the results. The displayResult isn't even an id but a class, so getElementById would give you undefined.

Comment: thank you.. i will try it.
hopefully i will get it done.

Comment: @OnkiHara hey.. it is not working.
i have uploaded it to codepen.io.. can u take a look please? i really need to understand what the issue is.

https://codepen.io/asafdanan/pen/gOKxgxX

Comment: change `const listComp = [];` into `let listComp = [];`. while `listComp` is constant, you cannot assign it to new value. thats why it is remaining empty. I guess it should work . it worked on codepen

Comment: @Saidamir
thank you so much..
can u explain to me how line 19 to 24 works? i actually copy pasted it.. and i really need to underrstand this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to display list items, if it doesn't break current functionality.

```
function presentData(data) {
  data.map((item) => {
    nasdaqLi.innerHTML += `<li style="list-style: none;">
      <a href="./company.html?symbol=${item.symbol}" target="_blank">${item.name} ${item.symbol}</a>
    </li>`
  })
  spinner.style.display = 'none';
  //console.log(data)
 }
```

So the idea is looping through the array of objects and creating list item for each object. `map` method loops through the array and takes the each object and applies the function provided which is creating list items.

Comment: thank you so much @Saidamir
could u please explain to me what target="blank" does?
and also all the innerHTML methods u provided there at line 3 to 5?
thanks.